# Application not open LAUNCHER activity

Tags: android

In my Application, activity for say A is launcher activity, from A it called B and from B it called C, I have such more than 3 activities. In C when I press home button, and again open my app it open C. But i want it always open launcher activity.

Answer (score 1):

Then perform finish() in onPause() call back method of every activity.
This may help you to get activity A as launcher every time even you press home button